# How to logically organize source files in C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, organization

My source file pane is quickly growing (in terms of the number of files in my project) and it is getting a bit cumbersome to quickly locate the specific source file I need to access at any given time. I'm using Embarcadero's C++Builder, but I have encountered this issue in other C++ IDEs as well.

In Java, I often utilize packages for creating logical divisions of my source code, especially when dealing with a large number of source files in a single project. While this, of course, isn't the only purpose of Java packages, they are very handy in this regard.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve similar functionality in C++? Should I separate my source into physical folders? Does C++Builder offer some kind of virtual folder/grouping functionality that I'm just not seeing? Any ideas are appreciated and thank you.

Comment: I typically navigate through the class browser instead of relying on source file organization.

Comment: Organize into folders. And if its big module, i would suggest make it into a project

Comment: Jeezo am I the wrong guy to ask. I'm so friggen anal about organization my IDE rarely has more than three source files open, and my projects are always setup with a src/ folder with potentially src/feature if things start to get hairy (which they rarely do since I'm not a big-bin advocate). Also a project include/ folder for cross-feature includes.

Comment: Visual Assist X helps with efficient location of source files in Visual Studio. VS is really lacking in that department compared to Xcode or even KDevelop.

Comment: I do not have any affiliation with Whole Tomato. I recently started working on Windows and really suffered from the deficiencies in Visual Studio, and the tool I mentioned above helped. And yes, I agree that it is standard functionality that really should be in VS. But it's not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I generally recommend **not** to use (only) the IDE or the language syntax for organizing your source code. For one, you tie yourself to the environment: well organized in the IDE, unorganized on file, and then comes the day when you might want to use a *different* environment...

Because of this, I usually use all three ways of organizing my source at the same time: I separate my source into functional modules, i.e. related classes. Each module gets its own namespace, physical folder, and IDE folder. (In my case, using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) and `source_group()` to generate IDE project files if needed -- personally preferring the command line, Vim, and "make".)

Hence, whether I look at the project from within the IDE, from the command line, or from a compiler log, foo/some_class.hpp is foo/some_class.cpp is foo::some_class, minimizing confusion all around.

Actually, my currently preferred setup further subdivides each module directory into `<project>/<module>/<class>.hpp` or `<project>/<module>/src/<class>.hpp` depending on whether the class is used outside its own module or not, `<project>/<module>/src/<class>.cpp`, and `<project>/<module>/test/<class>_tu.cpp`. Namespace is `<project>::<module>::<class>`, of course.

```
project
|-- foo
|   |-- some_class.hpp
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- internal_class.hpp
|   |   |-- internal_class.cpp
|   |   `-- some_class.cpp
|   `-- test
|       |-- internal_class_tu.cpp
|       `-- some_class_tu.cpp
|-- bar
|   |-- ...
```

The idea here is that the "external" interface of each module (`foo`) is documented by the headers in that subfolder, with implementation details and tests "hidden" in the respective subfolders.

But in the end, it very much depends -- on your taste, on that of your co-developers, and the scope of your project.

Comment: This seems like it will be the all-around best solution. Especially if my projects migrate to a different IDE in the future and since it will cover me on all fronts. Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: Perhaps you might be interested in [JAWS](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de) (something I have set up in the meantime)...

Answer (score 13):

This is how I roll:

```
PROJECT_NAME
|-- build // This is DVCS ignored but has all the built intermediates and final binaries
|   |-- release // These are the different build profiles
|   |-- debug
|   |-- profile
|   `-- coverage
|-- bin // For binary source code
|   `-- hello_world
|       |-- doc
|       |-- inc
|       |-- src
|       |-- tests
|       `-- build_script  // Builds binary into the build folder
|-- include // Public headers for the library
|   `-- these
|       `-- folders
|           `-- represent
|               `-- namespaces
|                   `-- my_awesome_class.hpp
|-- lib // library source code
|   |-- these
|   |   `-- folders
|   |       `-- represent
|   |           `-- namespaces
|   |               |-- inc // Private headers
|   |               |   `-- my_private_class.hpp // internal class
|   |               |-- src // Source code for this namespace
|   |               |   |-- posix
|   |               |   |   `-- my_awesome_class.cpp // posix specific source code
|   |               |   |-- nt
|   |               |   |   `-- my_awesome_class.cpp // nt specific source code
|   |               |   |-- my_private_class.cpp // non-visibile class
|   |               |   `-- my_awesome_class.cpp // cross platform source code
|   |               |-- tests // Unit tests
|   |               |   `-- my_awesome_class.cpp // builds a test executable for the library
|   |               `-- doc // Documentation for this namespace
|   |                   `-- namespace.dox
|   `-- build_script  // Builds binary into the build folder
|-- doc // Documentation files
|   |-- main_page.dox
|   `-- namespace.dox
`-- build_script  // Builds the source code into the build folder
```

This represents the `these::folders::represent::namespaces::MyAwesomeClass` class which has `posix` and `NT` specific source code (as well as generic source code) plus there is a private `these::folders::represent::namespaces::MyPrivateClass` that is used internally in the library, the headers are not public and the [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) of the class symbols are hidden.

This has scaled very well and provides easy locating of files.

Comment: out of source build is also quite neat. I'll suggest removing the `build` dir and build from `../build_whatever_mode`.

Answer (score 0):

I make projects in order to keep all my files easily accesible. It is the easiest way to organize, along with clear class/file names.

Comment: I actually indicated (in my first sentence, in fact) that what I'm dealing with __is__ a project. My problem is organizing the source files within that project. When dealing with a relatively large number of classes, giving them clear names simply isn't enough.